# De-serialize XML files with varying XmlRoot element names

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I have a large number of XML files that I need to perform de-serialization on. These files have varying root names (over 250). I'm trying to pass the root attribute name through XmlSerializer before accessing the XML class to retrieve my data. Here is what I have but I'm still getting an error that the root name was expected although the XmlElement class is passing the attribute to the XmlSerializer class.

The method used to retrieve the file:

```
string strXmlDoc = path;
XmlDocument objXmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
objXmlDoc.Load(strXmlDoc);
XmlElement objRootElem = objXmlDoc.DocumentElement;

XmlSerializer xmlSerial = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XMLFile), new XmlRootAttribute(objRootElem.ToString()));
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path);
XMLFile entity = xmlSerial.Deserialize(sr) as XMLFile;
```

The XML classes file:

```
[Serializable]
//[XmlRoot("randomname")] Removed this line since I'm getting the XmlRoot attribute in the XmlSerializer line.
public class XMLFile
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("RECORD")]
    public RECORD RECORD { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class RECORD
{
    [XmlElement("BK01")]
    public Record Bk01 { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("BK02")]
    public Record Bk02 { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Record
{
    [XmlAttribute("Value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Do you have control over serialized xml? Does it have to be XmlSerializer?

Comment: Are you saying that the type to which you want to deserialize is always the same, but the name of the root element in the XML varies?

Comment: @ScottHannen - Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @MikeDev I will not be editing the XML files, only viewing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
XmlSerializer xmlSerial = 
    new XmlSerializer(typeof(XMLFile), new XmlRootAttribute(objRootElem.ToString()));
```

to this:

```
XmlSerializer xmlSerial = 
    new XmlSerializer(typeof(XMLFile), new XmlRootAttribute(objRootElem.Name));
                                                                        ^^^
```

`XmlElement.ToString()` will always return `System.Xml.XmlElement`, which is not what you want.